# supported InterfaceOrientations iOS 8 vs. iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

A warning has occurred after I updated to the latest version of XCode (7.0).

```
conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUinteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

I'm guessing that

```
-(NSUinteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

is no longer supported in iOS 9 and I tried searching for some documentation on it but I couldn't find it.

So what is the best solution going forward?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a possible solution:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000  
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#else  
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#endif
```

Comment: If you are not planning on use Xcode 6 or any iOS SDK lower then 7 more you can remove the if and just keep `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations `.